# react native firebase not persisting user info

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

This is a plain vanilla user sign in app. When a user signs in, they should see the Home screen but for some reason it doesnt get to the Homescreen at all. Full App.js code is below.

I have a branching condition user ? goto Home : or just show the login/signup options. The user variable has a value of 'undefined'. Does this meant he value did not persist?

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { LoginScreen, HomeScreen, RegistrationScreen } from './src/screens'
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64'
import { firebase } from './src/firebase/config'


if (!global.btoa) {  global.btoa = encode }
if (!global.atob) { global.atob = decode }

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user)
        console.log('user is logged in  ')
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()  
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data()
            setLoading(false)
            setUser(userData)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false)
          });
      } else {
        console.log('user is not logged in')
        setLoading(false)
      }
    });
  }, []);
  
  
  console.log(user)

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <></>
    )
  }

  return (  
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        { user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: What logging output do you get from `console.log(user)`?

Comment: its undefined..

Comment: Just to be clear, the first console.log(user) in line no 6 produces a dump of all user variables.  The second console.log(user) produces 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

> Just to be clear, the first console.log(user) in line no 6 produces a dump of all user variables. The second console.log(user) produces 'undefined'.

That is the expected behavior.

Firebase automatically restores the user credentials from local storage when the app/page reloads. But this requires it to call the server, which takes some time and thus happens asynchronously. While this is going on your main code continues, and your second log shows (correctly) that the current user is still `undefined` at this point.

Then, when the user credentials are restored, your `onAuthStateChanged` callback is executed, it sets `user` and correctly logs the user's properties. And since you call `setUser(userData)` in there, this will also trigger React to re-render the component, so that it can show the updated user in `<HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />`.

Comment: thanks for the response. That totally makes sense. However, in my case it doesnt trigger the <HomeScreen...> component. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: I recommend setting breakpoints and running the code in a debugger. Does your `setUser(userData)` get triggered when you do that? If so, and if `userData` is different than it was before, that really should trigger React to update the UI.